# Getting random values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, random

I have a `String` array:

```
String [] array={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
```

Which I convert into an array list:

```
 ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

I want to get a random value from my ArrayList.

Comment: _is this possible in Android??_ Just a quick search on google would have answered your question.

Comment: i know i have done but it always showing me error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Random` class to do that, argument of method `nextInt` is the bound on the random number to be returned. It must be positive:

```
Random random = new Random();
yourList.get(random.nextInt(yourList.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Kotlin Solution

```
myList.random()
```

`random()` is a default extension function included in base Kotlin on the `Collection` object.

[Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html)