# Display random string from Array stored in values/ with Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin, random

I searched for a way to display in my TextView a random string from my array list stored in Values/Rarity.xml.

There are many examples here all in Java, but none are working.

I tried:
[kotlin Get random string from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183635/kotlin-get-random-string-from-array) (can't make it work with an array from my values/rarity.xml)

[Getting random values from an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925231/getting-random-values-from-an-arraylist/42925277)

I am new to Android studio and would like to know how to make it work, has I've been trying for the past few hours without success.

This is what I would like to achieve, but the app crash when I click on the button :

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rarity = arrayOf(R.array.wp_rarity)
        val randomRarity = rarity.random()

        btn_generate.setOnClickListener {
            item_type.setText(randomRarity)
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace the `val rarity = arrayOf(R.array.wp_rarity)` by `val rarity = arrayOf("test", "test2")` it does work but I would like to use my arrays in **values/*.xml** in order to optimize it. Or is there another way ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getStringArray` instead of `arrayOf`. It is method of collections. Try this

```
val rarity = resources.getStringArray(R.array.wp_rarity)
```

Comment: I used getStringArray however it's highlighted in RED and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to getResouce().getStringArray instead

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer ! To be more specific it was : `resources.getStringArray(R.array.wp_rarity)`

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by Cong Hai in the comments of his post.

It was :

```
val rarity = resources.getStringArray(R.array.wp_rarity)
```

Many thanks to him !